# C# constructor flaw

Tags: c#, constructor, static-members

Here's a part of my code:

```
class Tiger: Animal,IPredator
{
private double weight;
public static double AvgWeight;
public static int Population;
public static double TotalWeight;
public Tiger(double aWeight):this(aWeight,"Savannah"){}
public Tiger(double aWeight, params string[] aHabitat) : base(aWeight,"Panthera Tigris", "Mammalia", aHabitat)
{
    Population++;
    TotalWeight += Weight;
    AvgWeight = TotalWeight / Population;
    Console.WriteLine($"Let's all welcome our new Tiger: {Weight} kilos. Average pride weight: {AvgWeight}");
}
public  override double Weight
{
    get
    {
        return weight;
    }

    set
    {
        TotalWeight -= weight;
        weight = value;
        TotalWeight += weight;
        AvgWeight = TotalWeight / Population;
    }
}
```

Looks fine,but when I create an instance and check the constructor, it shows double the value of the new cat's weight.

Part of Animal's code:

```
 abstract class Animal
     {
    private string kind;
    private string @class;
    public List<string> Habitat = new List<string>();
    public virtual double Weight { get; set; }
    public string Kind { get { return kind; } set { } }
    public string @Class { get { return kind; } set { Console.WriteLine("Class cannot be changed"); } }

    public Animal(double aWeight,string aKind, string aClass,params string[] aHabitat)
    {
        kind = aKind;
        @class = aClass;
        Habitat.AddRange(aHabitat);
        Weight = aWeight;
    }
```

I was trying to avoid these issues, that's why I added an extra double field in Tiger. But I need the Tiger's to work like this and Animals should definitely have a Weight property.

Comment: you really should not be tracking that stuff in static variables

Comment: It is impossible for anyone to answer this question without seeing what Animal's constructors look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was not the inheritance or static methods. It was just the same string in the setter and the constructor: TotalWeight += value;